# gulp-imagemin optional dep failed

Tags: plugins, gulp, imagemin

As stated in the title, when i try to

```
npm install gulp-imagemin
```

It throws these errors:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@1.0.2
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@1.0.0
gulp-imagemin@1.0.1 node_modules/gulp-imagemin
├── object-assign@1.0.0
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.1 (get-stdin@1.0.0)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0,     has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── through2@0.6.2 (xtend@4.0.0, readable-stream@1.0.32)
├── gulp-util@3.0.1 (lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.8, minimist@1.1.0, lodash@2.4.1, vinyl@0.4.3, multipipe@0.1.1, lodash.template@2.4.1)
└── imagemin@1.0.5 (get-stdin@3.0.0, stat-mode@0.2.0, ware@0.3.0, tempfile@1.0.0, nopt@3.0.1, fs-extra@0.11.1, imagemin-svgo@1.0.2)
```

And the plugin doesn't work anymore, anyone knows what's going on? Thanks.

I'm on OSX Mavericks if this matters.

Comment: Have you tried `npm cache clean` ?

Comment: @Aperçu yeah and no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Image-min dependencies failed to install. Installing packages separately will fix the problem:

```
npm install imagemin-gifsicle imagemin-pngquant imagemin-optipng imagemin-jpegtran --save-dev
```